# generator function for getting database entries in javascript

Tags: javascript, sqlite, iterator, generator

I want to write code for a generator function which will return objects from database.

I have a database and it contains certain records. I want to write a function which will return result of select query in iterator form.

```
function *get(<searchquery>) 
{
}
```

I am using sqlite3 database. Any thoughts, pointers ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing how sqlite3 works, but I expect that you can fire a query against it that gives you some kind of object (likely a cursor, or iterator-like thing) that can tell you if there are more results left, and will allow you to get a result.

Some(pseudocode)thing like:

```
function* get( query ) {
    var handle = executeDatabaseQuery(query);
    while( handle.hasMoreResults() ) {
      yield handle.getOneResult();
    }
 }

var data=get("select * from thingsYouNeverDoInSQL");

var res;
while( (res=data.next()) && !res.done ) {
  console.log(res.value);
}
```